# Access route in store.js (Vuex/Nuxt)

Tags: nuxt.js

How can I access the route in the store.js file?

I want access to `path` and `fullPath` in store.js.

Comment: Why you need that? Viex has no path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to access `fullPath` inside store in Nuxt.js as below

fullPath: `this.$router.currentRoute.fullPath`

query: `this.$router.currentRoute.query`

Hope this will help you!

Comment: `this` is undefined inside store, how is this a proper answer?

Answer (score 3):

in your store, try with:

```js
this.app.router;
// for example :
this.app.router.push('/');
```

In this case:

```js
const correntPathInfo = this.app.router.currentRoute;
console.log(correntPathInfo);
```

Check this `issues` doc:

- https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/1384#issuecomment-348274658